# Loop through LastRow Index Match Index (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am newer to Google Apps Script and am trying to take this formula

```
=IF(S2<>0,INDEX(Rolling!$P:$P,MATCH(Q$1&$C2&$E2,INDEX(Rolling!$B:$B&Rolling!$C:$C&Rolling!$E:$E,0),0)),"N/A"))
```

and loop it from T2 to LastRow.

Basically I have data from today on the Current sheet and I'm trying to display the corresponding comments from the previous day on the same sheet.  The sheet that it is referencing is a rolling record from many days.  I am also trying to bring over the variance amount using a Sumifs formula, if that would be easier to show how to loop through a formula in GAS.

I ran the macro recorder (1st code) to get a rough idea, but am a little confused in how to start the loop.  I am trying to translate and understand how to set up the loop like the excel example (2nd code).

```js
function TestFormula() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('T2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IF(S2<>0,INDEX(Rolling!$P:$P,MATCH(Q$1&$C2&$E2,INDEX(Rolling!$B:$B&Rolling!$C:$C&Rolling!$E:$E,0),0)),"N/A")');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
};
```

```vb
Sub Add_ZARC2_1448()
    Worksheets("1448_SS").Activate
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim Arg1 As Range
    Dim Arg2 As Range
    Dim Arg3 As Range
    Dim Arg4 As Range
    Dim Arg5 As Range

    Set Arg1 = Worksheets("ZARC2").Range("G:G")
    Set Arg2 = Worksheets("ZARC2").Range("A:A")
    Set Arg3 = Worksheets("1448_SS").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1))
    Set Arg4 = Worksheets("ZARC2").Range("E:E")
    Set Arg5 = Worksheets("1448_SS").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(LastRow, 3))

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Worksheets("1448_SS").Cells(i, 13) _
            = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3.Cells(i - 1, 1), Arg4, Arg5.Cells(i - 1, 1))
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your macro seems fine and it should work. Do you have a problem?

Comment: The Excel macro works great, I am trying to figure out how to do something similar in Google Apps Script.  Or are you saying just use what the recorder did and don't try to rewrite it?

Comment: `Or are you saying just use what the recorder did and don't try to rewrite it?` Kinda. What's wrong with it? Click "Learn More" on [tag:google-apps-script] and search the official documentation on methods and how to use them.

Comment: If what you're trying is to automatically create the "IF" function as it's done in the Excel macro, you can't. You need to use a setFormula() function and set the entire formula manually.